# ficheros y diccionarios python

Tags: python, poo, spyder

necesito dos funciones, una que me lea un fichero y otra que me lo devuelva de la siguiente forma. Y no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

El fichero es el siguiente:

```
4,4,P06,2
1, 1, P01, 52
1, 1, P02, 1
1, 1, P03, 7
5,6, P04, 4
1, 2, P02, 20
1, 2, P03, 14
5,7, P04, 8
```

y me lo tiene que devolver de esta forma:

```
P06 : { (4, 4) : 2}
P01 : { (1, 1) : 52}
P02 : { (1, 1) : 1, (1, 2) : 20}
P03 : { (1, 1) : 7, (1, 2) : 14}
P04 : { (5, 6) : 4, (5, 7) : 8}
```

Comment: y el fichero esta en que formato?

Comment: Hola Miriam, recuerda que debes agregar lo intentado o investigado hasta el momento para que la pregunta sea bién recibida en el sitio. Tienes lineas con espacios al lado de la coma y otras sin ellas ¿es así o es un error al pegarlo aquí? La idea sería leer el archivo y linea a linea aplicar str.split para separar por la coma (o usar el módulo csv), luego creas un diccionario de diccionarios. La clave es la tercera columna, el valor otro diccionario en el que las  dos primeras serian la calve construyendo una tupla con ellas y la cuarta el valor.

Comment: Te quedaría un diccionario de la forma `{'P06': {(4, 4) : 2}
'P01': {(1, 1):  52}, 
'P02': {(1, 1): 1, (1, 2) : 20}, 
'P03': {(1, 1): 7, (1, 2) : 14}, 
'P04': {(5, 6):  4, (5, 7) :  8}}`. Luego lo puedes imprimir o lo que sea. Solo necesitas `open` para abrir el fichero, iterar sobre el con un `for`, aplicar `split` a cada linea e indizando obtener las cuatro columnas para construir la estructura. Confirma lo de la estructura del archivo (los espacios) e intenta algo, si no avanzas agrega el código. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

data.txt:

```
4,4,P06,2
1,1,P01,52
1,1,P02,1
1,1,P03,7
5,6,P04,4
1,2,P02,20
1,2,P03,14
5,7,P04,8
```

script.py:

```
def leer_archivo():
    file = open("data.txt","r")
    lista = []
    for linea in file.readlines():
        lista.append(linea.replace('\n',''))
    return lista


def imprimir(lista):
    diccionario = {}
    for l in lista:
        v1,v2,v3,v4= l.split(',')
        if not v3 in diccionario:
            diccionario[v3] = {(int(v1),int(v2)): int(v4)}
        else:
            diccionario[v3].update({(int(v1),int(v2)): int(v4)})

    for key, value in diccionario.items():
        print '%s: %s'%(key, str(value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lista = leer_archivo()
    imprimir(lista)
```